# Ubuntu 12.04 on Dell Latitude D610 along with Windows 7

Tags: installation, grub2, dual-boot, filesystem, dell

I have a Dell latitude D610 laptop with faulty screen so I use it as a desktop with its original dock. I have installed Windows 7 which is running fine. Hardware specs are as follows

Intel Pentium Mobile 1.7GHz
160GB HDD
2 GB RAM
D Link DWA125 USB Wireless Adapter

Last night I downloaded latest version of Ubuntu from it's official site and burnt it on a DVD. I chose 50% HDD (i.e 80GB) for Ubuntu and remaining half for Windows 7. Installation went fine. To my surprise Ubuntu recognized all hardware (WiFi, Audio, wireless keyboard, mouse etc.) and after the installation, it asked me to reboot (ejected the DVD by itself). The problem started after I rebooted, it switched to command line with lot of command run in a scrolling screen. It hanged on one line saying something like 'turning off all processes'. I thought it's doing something in the background. I left it running whole night and it was still stuck on the same screen in the morning. I forced restart it by power button. Grub shows several options

1. Ubuntu in normal mode
2. Ubuntu in recovery mode
3. something long
4. something log
5. Windows

First options takes me to complete blank screen and nothing happens. Even the monitor goes to power save mode.

Second option takes me to command line with lot of things scrolling on the screen and stops at a point saying something like 'File system read only'. Not quite sure to fix it.

I really want to try Ubuntu this time. Can anyone help?

Hashmi

Answer (score 1):

Please see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/162076/35775).

Start following instruction where it said, **Black/purple screen after you boot Ubuntu for the first time**.
 Don't pay attention to screenshots. Those are wrong. Once logged in Press  Alt+F2 and execute `gksudo jockey-gtk`. This will check for the graphics dirver that may be required.